# Resuming a parallel scan from where it left off

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I was looking into [parallel-scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan) for dynamodb. It has a concept of `segments` which each thread operates on.

Lets say the scan gets interrupted and we have the last-evaluated key for each thread, is there a reliable way to re-start the scan from where it left off.

The crucial question is how are the segments defined and are they defined in the same way across multiple runs of the parallel-scan? There doesn't seem to be much documentation on how the segments get defined.

Answer (score 1):

You have a thread for each parallel scan you do, if one fails, just redo that particular scan again. The data is divided mostly equally based on totalSegments and segmentId.

More information on how it works https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.ParallelScan

There is a working example in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html

Comment: Lets say I do a parallel scan and then interrupt it. Then I start the scan again. Would a given hashkey belong to the same segment in both the runs?

Comment: It may not, as the data might change meanwhile and will shift/shrink/enlarge the segment.